# no main manifest attribute, in xxx.jar [maven-assembly-plugin is not working]

Tags: java, pom.xml

I have maven-assembly-plugin in my pom.xml:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.xxx.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

so after building the project I got the xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar executable file. So as I run it in my terminal such as:

```
$ java -jar xxx.jar
```

it returns:

```
no main manifest attribute, in xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: how you create the `.jar` ? What command you using?

Comment: I tried in both netbeans and intellij. in netbeans I build the project, then I got the .jar file. in intellij View ->Tool Windows -> Maven and then execute package

Comment: try use command --> `mvn clean install`

Comment: I removed target folder, and I tried `mvn clean install` in terminal. I got `no main manifest attribute, in xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: issue solved ??

Comment: no! I am still getting `no main manifest attribute, in xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 10):

Your build creates an additional jar, that contains `jar-with-dependencies` in its name. You have to run this jar.

Comment: I just spent far too long working out why my jar file didn't work. This answer helped me find the additional jar!